# How to get number of processes and threads in a C program?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I would like to get the number of ALL running processes and ALL running threads of my Linux system. I need this information IN a C application. From the terminal, I can get his info with

```
$ ps -A --no-headers | wc -l
```

for processes and

```
$ ps -AL --no-headers | wc -l
```

for processes including tasks.

I didn't find this info in `/proc`.
Any suggestions?

Comment: [`popen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html)?

Comment: One linux way is to look in the virtual folder `proc/self/` eg `ls /proc/self/task -lL` shows the 1 thread ls has launched.

Comment: Are you looking for the processes/threads that are children of a given (C) process ? Or are you looking to query the total number of processes/threads *from* a C process ? I interpret your question as the latter, but others seem to interpret it as the former.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I wasn't clear enough. It would like to have the number of ALL processes and ALL thread running on my linux system. This must be done within my C application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest is to parse the output of commands using popen.

The following:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void parse_output(char *buf, size_t bufsize, const char cmd[]) 
{
    assert(buf != NULL);
    assert(cmd != NULL);

    FILE *fp;

    // add dynamic allocation here
    memset(buf, 0, bufsize);

    if ((fp = popen(cmd, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening pipe!\n");
        exit(-__LINE__);
    }

    // worst speed ever. And strlen is called twice...
    while (fgets(&buf[strlen(buf)], bufsize - strlen(buf), fp) != NULL);

    if(pclose(fp))  {
        printf("Command not found or exited with error status\n");
        exit(-__LINE__);
    }
}


int main() {
    char buf[256];
    long num;

    parse_output(buf, sizeof(buf), "ps -A --no-headers | wc -l");
    if (sscanf(buf, "%ld", &num) != 1) {
        exit(-__LINE__);
    }
    printf("Number of processes: %ld\n", num);

    parse_output(buf, sizeof(buf), "ps -AL --no-headers | wc -l");
    if (sscanf(buf, "%ld", &num) != 1) {
        exit(-__LINE__);
    }
    printf("Number of processes including tasks: %ld\n", num);

}
```

will output on my system:

```
$ gcc 1.c && ./a.out
Number of processes: 241
Number of processes includeing tasks: 867
```

Comment: after a while running this function i got this issue:

error: can not access /proc
error: can not access /proc
error: can not access /proc
Error opening pipe!
sscanf error process count
Error opening pipe!
sscanf error thread_count
Error opening pipe!
sscanf error process count
Error opening pipe!
sscanf error thread_count
Segmentation fault

Comment: `after a while`? `thread_count` ? `sscanf error process count`? `Segmentation fault`? This code just runs once and exists. These doesn't look like messages  from this code. Probably the best action would be to create a new question including an MCVE and including errors you posted.

Answer (score 3):

The `ps` examples in your question don't really give you the information you're asking about: the first lists *all* the processes on your system, not just those spawned by a particular program, and similarly the second lists the number of threads in *every* process.

If you want to find information about threads spawned by a particular process, you can look in `/proc` under `/proc/<pid>/task`.  For example, here is a process with a single thread:

```
bash-4.4$ ls /proc/15355/task/
15355
```

And here's one that has three threads (in addition to the main thread):

```
bash-4.4$ ls /proc/15295/task/
15295  15296  15297  15298
```

The corresponding `ps -L` output for that process looks like:

```
bash-4.4$ ps -L -p 15295
  PID   LWP TTY          TIME CMD
15295 15295 pts/4    00:00:00 python
15295 15296 pts/4    00:00:00 python
15295 15297 pts/4    00:00:00 python
15295 15298 pts/4    00:00:00 python
```

Getting the number of running processes from `/proc` takes a little more work, since Linux only maintains information about a process' parent, rather than it's children. That means you would need to scan through `/proc` and find every process for which the parent is your target process...and then repeat recursively for each of those processes.

You can use something like `pstree` to get this information, of course, but that output isn't really designed to be machine parseable.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough and edited my question. I indeed was asking for ALL processes and ALL threads running.

Answer (score 2):

Every running process has a corresponding directory `/proc/<pid>`. You can use that to count the number of running processes (by counting all sub-directories of `/proc` that are numeric).

Inside each of these directories you can check `/proc/<pid>/status` to get information about the process. Specifically, the line `Threads: <cnt>` gives you the number of threads for that process.

Refer to [`man proc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for more info on the `/proc` (pseudo) file system.